# ios gesture recognizers in overlapping views

Tags: ios

Hi I have a UIView which contains 2 subviews. One is a custom UIView and the other is a MPMoviePlayerController. The MPMoviePlayerController, I assume, has a UITapGestureRecognizer that displays the controls when you tap it. My custom UIView has a UIPanGestureRecognizer. Both views occupy the same coordinate space in it's superview. My custom UIView is layered on top of the MPMoviePlayerController. My problem is that tap events aren't delivered to the MPMoviePlayerController.

What I want is when a drag or pan event is recognized, then don't pass any gesture or touch information along to the MPMoviePlayerController. However, if the drag event is not recognized, such as when the user just taps on the screen, then I want the tap event to be passed to the MPMoviePlayerController.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Add Tap recognized to your own screen too. So you'll have two recognizers. If tap recognizer activate your selector try to tell movie player control this info. It's tap selector is already public, I think.